# Android set button pressed on click

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am dynamically creating a table of ImageButton, I would like to have setPressed to true for the image button. when it's clicked by the user. Since I have created the buttons dynamically, how do I setPressed using onClickListener?

```
        {
            ImageButton b = new ImageButton(this);
            b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                onClickListenerForTag("tagStr");
                            }
            }
        }

    private void onClickListenerForTag(final String tagStr) {
            assert (tagStr != null);
                    mTagStr = tagStr;
                    //need to call setPressed(true) here ?

        }
```

Comment: What object do you want to `setPressed(true)` on?

Comment: @slayton for the image buttons that i am creating dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `View` being passed in to the handler is the button instance. Cast the `Button` and call the method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     onClickListenerForTag("tagStr", v);
    }

private void onClickListenerForTag(final String tagStr, View v) {
            assert (tagStr != null);
            mTagStr = tagStr;

            ImageButton button = (ImageButton)v;
            button.setPressed(true);
    }
```